# LibGit2Sharp TypeInitializationException in Web project

Tags: asp.net, exception, visual-studio-2012, libgit2sharp

I use VS 2012. My solution contains one web-site project and one project library .

I installed the nuget package on my project Library only.

In my Library I created a simple class "GitRepo" to test git access. In the constructor, I want to access the repository :

```
public GitRepo(string repoPathName)
{
    m_Repo = new Repository(repoPathName);
}
```

In the code behind of my web page, I try to instantiate a GitRepo object :

```
GitRepo repo = new GitRepo(repoPathName);
```

And I get the TypeInitializationException with no more details. And yes, dll and native libraries structure seems correct in the file tree (installed by nuget package).

I have a simple console program's solution where I added my previous library (add existing object). In the "main" function, I instantiate a "GitRepo" object... and it works fine.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Here the full exception :

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods'.
  Source=LibGit2Sharp
  TypeName=LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods
  StackTrace:
       à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_repository_open(RepositorySafeHandle& repository, FilePath path)
       à LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
       à LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options)
       à CDM.ESD1_WSGINSTALL.Business.GitRepo..ctor(String repoPathName) dans c:\PRIV\Projects\ESD1\ESD1_WSGINSTALL\ESD1_WSGINSTALL.Business\GitRepo.cs:ligne 39
       à CDM.ESD1WSGINSTALL.Commands.CharteView.DoBuildRPM(String id) dans c:\PRIV\Projects\ESD1\ESD1_WSGINSTALL\ESD1_WSGINSTALL\App_Code\Commands\CharteViewActivity\CharteView.cs:ligne 262
  InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
       HResult=-2146233052
       Message=Impossible de charger la DLL 'git2-e0902fb': Le module spécifié est introuvable. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007007E)
       Source=LibGit2Sharp
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init()
            à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor()
            à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Regarding the `TypeInitializationException` exception, could you please share the full message along with the stack trace?

Comment: Could you please share as well the NuGet installation log along with the returned error when you try to install the package in your web-project?

Comment: What's the bit-ness of your libgit2 binaries?  IIS will by default try to load the binary into a 64 bit process. As such, you need to have either the x64 binaries or to configure IIS to run in 32-bit mode.

Comment: I added the exception. I use the ASP.Net development server, not IIS for the moment.

Comment: There is more detail in the error, it can't find `git2-e0902fb.dll`: Message=Impossible de charger la DLL 'git2-e0902fb': Le module spécifié est introuvable. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007007E).

Comment: I changed (simplify) my comments. The library call works from a console application. It's weird.

Comment: As it works from the console program, I wonder if the native libraries (git2....dll) are reachable from the main library in the web server environment.

Comment: I can't repro the issue. I've created a MVC project, successfully referenced the NuGet package, changed the `HomeController` to make `ViewBag.Message` set with `GlobalSettings.Version`. I ran it against the development server and the About page displayed the expected data. `Version` invokes some libgit2 native code behind the scene. So not having it throwing is usually a good sign that the git2-e0902fb.dll' has been found ;-)

Comment: I then uninstalled the NuGet package from the web app, create a class library project and made it reference the NuGet package. Inside the library, I've added a static class with a property that was returning the content of `GlobalSettings.Version`. I then changed the about web page to leverage the static class from the library. Ran it. It worked as well.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. Can you confirm that you can successfully reproduce my steps (from a blank web project) as well?

Comment: @jessehouwing The LibGit2Sharp package contains both the x86 and the amd64 compiled version of the native binaries. The managed layer probes for the bitness of the running process in order to determine which one should be loaded and interop'ed against.

Answer (score 1):

nulltoken, thank you for your help.I've started a new console project and added my library located in another folder. When I instanciate my "GitRepo" object (from my library) there's no exception. So I checked the directory tree of the solution and I saw that LibGit2Sharp.dll and NativeBinaries folder were added automatically under bin/debug of the program's folder.

Thus I checked the bin folder of my web project and I saw there was not the "NativeBinaries" folder. I add it manually and now there's no more exception.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't have to perform the copy by yourself. Something's fishy here.

The NuGet package referenced by your library should ensure that projects that depend on the library get a copy of `NativeBinaries` in their own output folder on build.

Comment: I'm sure you're right but, as I wrote in my first version of message, I got an installation problem on my first attempt to install the package on my web-site project. I don't want to uninstall (manually ?) and re-install the package to check. Now it works and I need to go forward :-)